# Converting complex MySQL query to UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a quite complex Mysql query:

```
SELECT 
    metabase_field.description, rows_to_copy.description,
    metabase_field.display_name, rows_to_copy.display_name
FROM 
  metabase_field LEFT JOIN (select id as table_id, name as t_name from metabase_table) metabase_field_table ON  metabase_field.table_id=metabase_field_table.table_id,
    (
        SELECT metabase_field.name as name, metabase_field_table.t_name as t_name, metabase_field.display_name as display_name, metabase_field.description as description, metabase_field.special_type as type
        FROM metabase_field
        LEFT JOIN  (select id as table_id, name as t_name, db_id, active, visibility_type from metabase_table) metabase_field_table ON metabase_field.table_id = metabase_field_table.table_id
        LEFT JOIN metabase_database metabase_field_table_database ON metabase_field_table.db_id = metabase_field_table_database.id
        where metabase_field_table.active=1 and metabase_field_table.visibility_type is null and metabase_field_table_database.name = 'Prod'
    ) as rows_to_copy
WHERE
    metabase_field_table.table_id IN (
        SELECT distinct(metabase_table.id) as ids
        from metabase_table
        LEFT JOIN metabase_database metabase_table_database ON metabase_table.db_id = metabase_table_database.id
        where metabase_table_database.name = 'Dev' and metabase_table.active=1 and metabase_table.visibility_type is null
    )
    and metabase_field_table.t_name = rows_to_copy.t_name
    and metabase_field.name = rows_to_copy.name
```

This returns a table looking a bit like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| description | description | display_name | display_name |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| NULL        | to copy     | Application  | Application  |
```

Without going to deep into details, I just wanted to copty results from rows_to_copy to metabase_field fields, which means to set:

> metabase_field.description = rows_to_copy.description,
>       metabase_field.display_name = rows_to_copy.display_name

I tried to just change SELECT to UPDATE:

```
UPDATE
  metabase_field LEFT JOIN (select id as table_id, name as t_name from metabase_table) metabase_field_table ON  metabase_field.table_id=metabase_field_table.table_id,
    (
        SELECT metabase_field.name as name, metabase_field_table.t_name as t_name, metabase_field.display_name as display_name, metabase_field.description as description, metabase_field.special_type as type
        FROM metabase_field
        LEFT JOIN  (select id as table_id, name as t_name, db_id, active, visibility_type from metabase_table) metabase_field_table ON metabase_field.table_id = metabase_field_table.table_id
        LEFT JOIN metabase_database metabase_field_table_database ON metabase_field_table.db_id = metabase_field_table_database.id
        where metabase_field_table.active=1 and metabase_field_table.visibility_type is null and metabase_field_table_database.name = 'Prod'
    ) as rows_to_copy
SET
    metabase_field.description = rows_to_copy.description,
    metabase_field.display_name = rows_to_copy.display_name
WHERE
    metabase_field_table.table_id IN (
        SELECT distinct(metabase_table.id) as ids
        from metabase_table
        LEFT JOIN metabase_database metabase_table_database ON metabase_table.db_id = metabase_table_database.id
        where metabase_table_database.name = 'Dev' and metabase_table.active=1 and metabase_table.visibility_type is null
    )
    and metabase_field_table.t_name = rows_to_copy.t_name
    and metabase_field.name = rows_to_copy.name
;
```

But this query doesn't seem to change anything - the results stay the way they were. Is there any simple way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Update metabase_field set metabase_field.description=
     rows_to_copy.description, metabase_field.display_name=
    rows_to_copy.display_name  LEFT JOIN (select id as table_id, name as
     t_name from metabase_table) metabase_field_table ON
 metabase_field.table_id=metabase_field_table.table_id, ( SELECT
   metabase_field.name as name, metabase_field_table.t_name as t_name,
     metabase_field.display_name as display_name,metabase_field.description as description, metabase_field.special_type
 as type FROM metabase_field LEFT JOIN (select id as table_id, name as
    t_name, db_id, active, visibility_type from metabase_table)
   metabase_field_table ON metabase_field.table_id =
 metabase_field_table.table_id LEFT JOIN metabase_database
 metabase_field_table_database ON metabase_field_table.db_id =
  metabase_field_table_database.id where metabase_field_table.active=1
   and metabase_field_table.visibility_type is null and
   metabase_field_table_database.name = 'Prod' ) as rows_to_copy WHERE
     metabase_field_table.table_id IN ( SELECT distinct(metabase_table.id)
    as ids from metabase_table LEFT JOIN metabase_database
    metabase_table_database ON metabase_table.db_id =
     metabase_table_database.id where metabase_table_database.name = 'Dev'
     and metabase_table.active=1 and metabase_table.visibility_type is null
     ) and metabase_field_table.t_name = rows_to_copy.t_name and
    metabase_field.name = rows_to_copy.name
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

After some formating I realize if almost imposible keep track of table names. use shorter and different alias to avoid bugs. I try to improve the rest of the code but too much work

I think the problem is the update. Update table should have the alias MF, and you `SET MF.<field>`

If that doesnt work, remove the `WHERE` and see if you `UPDATE` something. Of course only if you can do testing on those tables.

If that doesnt work, start with a single table and add one join at each time.

```
UPDATE  metabase_field MF -- main alias for table to update.
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id as table_id, name as t_name 
           FROM metabase_table) MT1
  ON  MF.table_id = MT1.table_id      
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MF1.name as name, 
                    MT2.t_name as t_name, 
                    MF1.display_name as display_name,
                    MF1.description as description, 
                    MF1.special_type as type
             FROM metabase_field MF1
             LEFT JOIN  (SELECT id as table_id, 
                                name as t_name, 
                                db_id, active, 
                                visibility_type 
                         from metabase_table) MT2
               ON MF1.table_id = MT2.table_id
             LEFT JOIN metabase_database MD
               ON MT2.db_id = MD.id
             WHERE MT2.active = 1 
               and MT2.visibility_type is null 
               and MD.name = 'Prod'
    ) as rows_to_copy
SET
    MF.description = rows_to_copy.description,
    MF.display_name = rows_to_copy.display_name
WHERE
    metabase_field_table.table_id IN (
        SELECT distinct(metabase_table.id) as ids
        from metabase_table
        LEFT JOIN metabase_database MB
          ON MT2.db_id = MB.id
        WHERE MB.name = 'Dev' 
          and MT2.active=1 
          and MT2.visibility_type is null
    )
    and metabase_field_table.t_name = rows_to_copy.t_name
    and metabase_field.name = rows_to_copy.name
;
```

Comment: Seems to be breaking on `Unknown column 'MT2.active' in 'where clause'`. Should I change MT2 to MF1?
EDIT: Changin also results in `Unknown column 'MF1.active' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @Niemand This is just a suggestion. As I say query is too big to try to make the edit here. But hope you can see is more readable using short different alias than name everything `matebase_field`